# get between two words multiple times php

Tags: php

```
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    $i++;    
    $word1 = '"';
    $word2 = '"';
    preg_match('/'.preg_quote($word1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($word2).'/is', $html, $match);
    echo $match[1]."<br>";
    $main = explode('"',$html);
    $html = $main[1];
    //echo $main[1];
}
```

This is code im currently using. but is not working. all i want to do is get between " . link "text" or link src="" get src. I can easily get between " but how can i get all the matched words? I want to create a function to do this job. like
Get_Text($result_array,$start_tag,$end_tag,$html); where $result_array is result and $start_tag is starting word link src=" and $end_tag is ending word like ". and $html is text in which i want to search
    EDIT :

Word 1 is (src=")

Word 2 is (")

```
html is (bla bla bla <iframe src="http://website.domain"></iframe> bla bla bla <embed src="url"></embed>)
```

now result should be
$result[1] = "http://website.domain";
$result[2] = "url"

Comment: Don't use regexp to parse HTML, use a DOM parser.

Comment: Does `preg_match_all()` do what you want, so you don't have to write a loop?

Comment: yeah may be. can you give me an example?

Comment: It's hard to tell, your code is very confusing (what's $word1 and $word2, you assign them each iteration?) Can you edit your question to show sample input and desired output?

Comment: can you understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_text_between ($start, $end, $string) {
  $start = preg_quote($start);
  $end = preg_quote($end);
  preg_match_all("/$start(.*?)$end/is", $string, $match);
  return $match[1];
}

$result = get_text_between('src="', '"', 'bla bla bla <iframe src="http://website.domain"></iframe> bla bla bla <embed src="url"></embed>');
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://website.domain
    [1] => url
)
```

However, using regexp to parse HTML is generally a bad idea. This won't work if the HTML has spaces between `src` and `=`, or the HTML uses single quotes instead of double quotes, etc. You should use a DOM parser library, PHP has several of them.